# Confused on lists: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: string, list, int

I have a program with numerous lists and have been assigning variables to them with ease, except for one list. Quick rundown on program, I open up lsblk to check disks, save to a file. I then remove a disk with a .sh file, and then scan to see what the new list is. I compare the two lists for differences, then read the differences and scan for integers, and pull the first int out to ultimately save it back to a list called diskchange. see below:

```
diskchange = [None]*5

for i in range(1,3):
    # Initial disk scan
    lsblk = subprocess.Popen(['lsblk'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    scan1 = [line.strip() for line in lsblk.stdout if 'nvme' in line]

    # Disable the slot to get ready to record which drive number disappeared
    with open('removeslot%d.sh' %i, 'rb') as file:
        script = file.read()
    subprocess.call(script, shell=True)

    lsblk = subprocess.Popen(['lsblk'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    scan2 = [line.strip() for line in lsblk.stdout if 'nvme' in line]

    for i in scan1:
        if i not in scan2:
                result = result + i

    disk = filter(str.isdigit, result)
    strdiskchange = str(disk)
        disk = int(strdiskchange[0])
    print disk
    print type(disk)
    print type(diskchange)
    diskchange[i] = disk
        print("The new disk added to slot %i is /dev/nvme%sn1" %(i, diskchange[i]))
```

You can see me trying to diagnose the issue with some print statements, and here is the output:

```
0
<type 'int'>
<type 'list'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "GUIArduino.py", line 61, in <module>
diskchange[i] = disk
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

0 is the final value pulled from result, i print the type of disk to the screen to show that it is of type int, i also have diskchange printed as type list, but I cannot store the int to the list for some reason.

I tried changing the initial value of disk = [] to None, 0, 1, '', with no changes. I also tried str(disk) int(disk) and the likes.

even just typing diskchange[i] = 0 gives the same message. Which has me the most confused

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are reusing the variable `i` for two different loops. Normally this would be OK but because the loops are inside each other, `i` is being overridden.

Comment: Wow, such a minor mistake. Thankyou for saving me some headache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're shadowing your for-loop `i` with another `i`:

```
for i in range(1,3):
    # type(i) is int
    …
    for i in scan1:
        …
    # type(i) is str
    …
    diskchange[i] = disk # i is str() here, so it yells at you!
```

Change your inner loop's index from `i` to `j` and you should be fine.

In python, the variable's visibility is over a full function, not a block. 
So when you're defining a variable within a block, it's still visible after the block:

```
 i = 'foobar'
 print(i, type(i))
 for i in range(100):
     pass
 print(i, type(i))
```

will give:

```
foobar str
100 int
```

so be careful when reusing variable names.

To fix your issue, just change the index name to `j`:

```
for j in scan1:
    if j not in scan2:
            result = result + j
```

---

bonus:

In the following snippet, you're reading the full content of a script to execute it by sending its whole content to a shell:

```
with open('removeslot%d.sh' %i, 'rb') as f:
    script = f.read()
subprocess.call(script, shell=True)
```

this is actually over engineered, you can simply do:

```
subprocess.call('removeslot%d.sh' % i, shell=True)
```

to execute the script (or `'bash removeslot%d.sh' % i` in case your `.sh` is not executable). Also beware that you're again shadowing a symbol: `file` is the class for handling files that is globally available. Use `f` instead!

HTH